# How to make the resolution of the plotoutput reactive, shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The res of plotOutput is not reacitve, Now I can only refresh the resolution by clicking the actionButton

For a high degree of customization in my shinyapp, the ggplot object has to be generated after the actionButton event, and be reactive, so in my minimal example I did that as well

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("bar_aes", label = "aes", choices = c("class", "displ")),
  selectInput("plot_res", label = "res", choices = c("72", "300", "600")),
  actionButton("bar_plot", label = "plot the bar"),
  uiOutput("plot_ui")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$bar_plot, {
    bar <- reactive({
      ggplot(mpg, aes_string(input$bar_aes)) + geom_bar()
    })
    output$plot <- renderPlot({bar()}, res = as.numeric(input$plot_res))
    output$plot_ui <- renderUI({plotOutput("plot")})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```r
    observeEvent(input$plot_res, {
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        bar()
      }, res = as.numeric(input$plot_res))
    })
```

but enclosing an output slot in an observer is considered as a bad practice. But I don't see any other solution.